# Поразрядная сортировка со списками. Не могу придумать, как поддерживать вложенность массивов для произвольного числа разрядов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Поразрядная сортировка массива со списками. Не могу придумать, как поддерживать вложенность массивов для произвольного числа разрядов. Получилось только для двух разрядов, и то с помощью условников.

реализация сортировки похожа на MSD(Most Significant Digit radix sort), только здесь используются вложенные списки(по итогу получается многомерный массив):

1. распределение исходного массива чисел по 10 массивам взависимости от числа старшего разряда(от 0 до 9)
2. следующий разряд распределяется по такому же принципу(10 массивов) но уже по найденым массивам на первом шаге. и т.д.
3. В итоге получаем многомерный массив, а после его объединения в один массив получаем отсортированную последовательность

   ```
   #преобразование многомерного массива в один массив
    def set_mass(mass):
        arr = []
        for i in mass:
            if type(i) != list:
                arr.append(i)
            else:
                arr += set_mass(i)
        return arr

    #начало программы

    list_0 = [[] for i in range(10)] # 10 списков для сортировки чисел (корзины: 0, 1, 2 ... 9)
    mass = [1, 22, 50, 4, 66, 5, 1, 0] # исходный массив
    length = len(str(max(mass))) # максимальное число разрядов

    # преобразование массива для сортировки по разрядам
    mass_num = []
    for num in mass:
        count_zero = length - len(str(num))
        mass_num.append('0' * count_zero + str(num))

    mass_f = []

    for i in range(length):
        # сортировка по первому разряду
        if i == 0:
            for num in mass_num:
                discharge = int(num[i]) # вычисление номера массива, в который нужно вставить число
                list_0[discharge].append(num)

        # сортировка по второму разряду
        if i == 1:
            for mass in list_0:
                list_2 = [[] for j in range(10)]
                for num in mass:
                    discharge = int(num[i])
                    list_2[discharge].append(int(num))
                mass_f.append(list_2)

    #отсортированный массив
    print(set_mass(mass_f))
   ```

Если все сделать так как сказал Stanislav Volodarskiy, появится ошибка, вот например при таком массиве:

```
mass = [1, 22, 10123, 4, 66, 5, 1000, 0]
```

Получим:

```
mass = [0, 1000, 1, 22, 4, 5, 66, 10123]
```

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy это очень хорошая идея. Но я хочу поддерживать структуру вложенных списков доконца, до последнего разряда и уже в конце объединить в один массив. Пока не выходит.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy вы немного ошиблись

Comment: Идея была плохая. Это вообще был LSD radix sort.

Answer (score 2):

[Most Significant Digit radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Most_significant_digit,_forward_recursive) рекурсивный. Значит рекурсия.

Следуя идеям из вопроса превращаем целые без знака в строки равной длины. Короткие строки дополняются слева (`rjust`) нулями:

```
# <- [1, 22, 50, 4, 66, 5, 1, 0]
# -> 2, ['01', '22', '50', '04', '66', '05', '01', '00']
def align(a):
    aa = list(map(str, a))
    max_len = max(map(len, aa))
    return max_len, [v.rjust(max_len, '0') for v in aa]
```

Теперь сортировка. Она рекурсивная. Сортируем старшие цифры, в получившихся корзинах сортируем следующие цифры и так далее:

```
# <- 0, 2, ['01', '22', '50', '04', '66', '05', '01', '00']
# -> [[['00'], ['01', '01'], ['04'], ['05']], [['22']], [['50']], [['66']]]
def sort_by_digit(i, n, a):
    if i >= n:
        return a
    bins = [[] for _ in range(10)]
    for v in a:
        bins[int(v[i])].append(v)
    return [sort_by_digit(i + 1, n, b) for b in bins if len(b) > 0]
```

Результат сортировки - сбалансированное дерево (все поддеревья одной высоты). Его нужно обойти:

```
# <- 2, [[['00'], ['01', '01'], ['04'], ['05']], [['22']], [['50']], [['66']]]
# -> ['00', '01', '01', '04', '05', '22', '50', '66']
def merge(n, bins):
    if n == 0:
        yield from bins
    else:
        for b in bins:
            yield from merge(n - 1, b)
```

Превращаем строки обратно в числа:

```
# <- ['00', '01', '01', '04', '05', '22', '50', '66']
# -> [0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 22, 50, 66]
list(map(int, ...))
```

Всё вместе:

```
# <- [1, 22, 50, 4, 66, 5, 1, 0]
# -> [0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 22, 50, 66]
def msd_radix_sort(a):
    n, aa = align(a)
    tree = sort_by_digit(0, n, aa)
    return list(map(int, merge(n, tree)))
```